# What does the FAA define as an "Aeronautical feat"?

Tags: faa-regulations

I got interested about [49 U.S.C. § 44724](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/49/44724), which arose following the death of a [7-year-old pilot attempting to set a record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessica_Dubroff). The new law says:

> ...  the individual is attempting to set a record or engage in an aeronautical competition or aeronautical feat, as defined by the Administrator.

1. What is the definition of an *aeronautical feat* and
2. Where, i.e. in what register, AC, LoI, etc..., is it defined *by the Administrator*?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a specific link, but an aeronautical feat would be an act of some uniqueness or difficulty, or unusual combination of features, especially one qualifying as the first successful achievement of such an act.

i.e.
First controlled powered flight, Flying non-stop from NY to Paris, First 747 commercial flight, First all-female crew, First to break the sound barrier, orbit the earth etc.

In US Law "The Administrator" is the person nominated to lead the FAA, or any of his staff he has delegated authority to.  The Administrator obviously has a large organization to manage, but the administrator is responsible for all of it's decisions and rules.  Similar language applies to all the other offices in a legal sense i.e. "The Secretary" of Interior, "The Secretary" of Transportation, "The Attorney General" of DOJ etc, etc.

Comment: Probably in many cases a first. But probably in some cases just something that is not common because of its difficulty. A famous example was Douglas (Wrong Way) Corrigan's unapproved nonstop solo flight across the Atlantic (New York to Ireland) in 1938, eleven years after Lindbergh flew New York to Paris.

Answer (score 0):

The Administrator, or the Administrator of the FAA is the head of the Federal Aviation Administration. Currently, [the position is held by one Michael Whitaker with Katie Thompson serving as Deputy Administrator](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/FAA_Org_Chart_4.pdf).

Feat is not currently defined under the code of federal regulations (CFRs).  The New Oxford American Dictionary defines the word feat as “an endeavor that requires great courage, skill, or strength.”  Applied to aeronautics, most likely this is a reference to a risky or difficult flight, or one performed by an individual not usually attempting such things i.e. a child or similar.